# How can i deal with instruments hanging issue?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instrumentation

I am stuck with instruments for iPad app.I am developing app with map view.I can run instruments with iPhone for memory leaks and it's work fine.But problem is that for same code and same app instruments is not running with ipad.I checked my entire code but there is no such problem.Even Instruments is running with iPad simulator for same code.

If i start interments after loading my app on my device than it will give following message.

Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'iPad (v4.3.5)' ((null))

I am using Xcode 4.0.2

Please Help me,
Thanks In ADvanced.